# Proving $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),m_{\rho})$ is $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove that  $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),m_{\rho})$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Here, the $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $m_{\rho}$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated with an increasing right-continuous function $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm getting really confused as to how to choose an appropriate cover for $\mathbb{R}$ since I barely know anything about $\rho$. Should I just take bounded sets?

I'd love any help, I really think I'm missing the point here!

Comment: Each set $(-n,n]$ has finite $\rho$ measure.

Comment: @Umberto P. Thank you! That's what I was thinking but I'm not sure I'm confident with proving that... Is right-continuity enough to ensure $\rho$ is bounded on each of these sets? Is that using the increasing feature at all?

Comment: @Kika $m_{\rho}((-n,n])=\rho(n)-\rho(-n)<\infty$ That's enough.

Comment: I'm sure I'm being silly but couldn't that be infinite?

Comment: $\rho$ is a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. You cannot have $\rho(n)=\infty$.

Comment: I'm unbelievably sorry, I was getting worried by nothing at all! Thank you so much, both of you!